Zooming in/out does not accurately use the mouse position
Whenever I am zooming in/out it displaces the mouse cursor and it does not actually zoom in where I put my mouse
Using a BarChart
Using: "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "2.0.1"

I tried using different charts (LineChart), this resulted in it working sometimes. It would zoom in correctly for some data points but not all

